# Removing SpecialType Blank Cells using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This script "works", but only if I run it twice.  Anyone have an idea of why this is happening?  Dealing with the special types has been somewhat of a nightmare, I'm not sure if that's just me or known issues.  Using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.  I've tried repeating the code twice as well to no avail.  I tried putting this in a Do Until and ALWAYS get stuck in a forever loop the first time I execute.  I'm not sure why executing it the second time seems to work

```
'Remove all Blank Cells

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count To 1 Step -1
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

  If Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count = 0 Then 
     ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
```

Comment: Hey Jeff, are you trying to go through a range and delete all rows where there are blank cells?

Comment: I am.  I tried doing a:
For each specialcell in range(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))
  specialcell.entirerow.delete
  next specialcell

and got the same results

Comment: I see what you mean. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: The first time through it doesn't seem to pick up the specialtypes, the count reads as empty until I execute the second time...Which maybe means I could to execute it while the specialcell count is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated answer to show how deleting a "specialcells" range doesn't reset the sheet's `UsedRange` property, and how that can lead to problems.

Try running this sub multiple times on a sheet with or without the call to `Activesheet.UsedRange` commented out...

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "have empty cells"
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Else
        Debug.Print "no empty cells"
    End If

End Sub
```

Saving and re-opening seems to also reset UsedRange...

**EDIT2** you should be very careful using this!  It deletes whole rows **even if there are non-blank cells in that row**.  It will be OK for certain types of data layout, but not for others.  Under certain circumstances you may also see an error "Cannot use that command on overlapping selection" when calling "delete".

Comment: thank you - using a slight variation, I was able to delete rows where column E is blank with: `Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: This produces the same behavior.  Two executes until it works.

Comment: @jeff - what is on your sheet?  And what happens if you remove the error handler?

Comment: Tim it is the same answer as me :) I had to delete it as it doesn't work :)

Comment: Nothing at all happens without the error handler.  From the behavior I'm seeing, the script treats the cells as if they don't exist until the 2nd execution.  When I remove the error handler the 2nd execution gives the error that no cells were found, and the blanks are gone.  But they certainly aren't gone after the 1st execution.

Comment: @Siddharth: See my edit: on some testing I agree it doesn't "seem" to work, but I think it does (you do need the error handling as well though, in case there are no blanks). The problem seems to be that calling `.Delete` doesn't seem to reset the sheet's `UsedRange` property, and SpecialCells seems itself to depend on UseDrange. If you add `Activesheet.UsedRange` (to trigger a reset) immediately after the `.Delete` you get different behavior on re-running.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much.  I've been wrangling with this for hours now.

Comment: + 1 Yup `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` was the key!

Comment: If you remove that then it will error with "No cells were found" if there are no blank cells...

Comment: True. i guess i should to go to bed!

Answer (score 0):

I'll caveat this by saying that @TimWilliams's answer is more elegant, but you can try this:

```
Sub Deletes()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

' Check each cell in the range and if its value is empty, delete the row
For Each Cell In rng
  If Cell.Value = "" Then
    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next Cell

' Close
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```